# Mot générique pour désigner l'arrêt de la capacité à se reproduire

Tags: vocabulaire, demande-de-mot, biologie

Je travaille sur un projet où la capacité de se reproduire d'organismes divers et pas forcément sexués occupe une certaine importance. Cependant, je n'arrive pas à trouver de mot exact pour désigner « l'arrêt de la capacité à se reproduire » lorsque celle-ci est naturelle et due à l'âge.

Dans un contexte humain, j'aurais parlé de *ménopause* ou d'*andropause*. Cependant, ces termes sont extrêmement sexués, globalement orientés pour désigner nos conditions humaines pour la reproduction et absolument pas taillés pour représenter un phénomène équivalent chez un organisme asexué (prenons le cas d'un organisme dont le comportement méiotique ne serait plus possible passé un certain âge).

Le terme *stérilité* est cependant trop large car il inclue également d'autres causes que l'âge ; le mot *sénescence* quant à lui me paraît également trop large car il touche tous les mécanismes d'un organisme et pas seulement le mécanisme de reproduction.

Existe-t-il donc un terme générique dans la langue française qui puisse représenter l'arrêt naturel des fonctions de reproduction d'un organisme dû à l'âge ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

J’ai cherché @Morwenn mais en vain :/
Je ne trouve dans aucun ouvrage de référence de terme générique pour désigner l’arrêt des capacités reproductives.

Comme dans tous les cas pareils je t’invite, comme te le propose @mouviciel, à créer ton néologisme :) Sachant que l’activité néologique est très intense dans le milieu scientifique, tu as encore moins de raisons d’hésiter ^^

Cela dit, si méiopause @mouviciel ne te convient toujours pas, que dis-tu de **gonopause** ?

Comment: De tout ce que j'ai pu voir, il n'existe en effet pas de terme représentant exactement le concept que je cherche. Si un tel mot avait occupé une place importante dans un papier de recherche ou un projet dédié, j'aurais sûrement utilisé un néologisme. Mais là, il s'agissait d'un banal projet scolaire ; j'ai simplement remplacé le mot par sa définition.

Comment: Très bien :) Mais à mon avis, tu ne devrais pas hésiter à créer ce néologisme fut-ce pour un « banal projet scolaire (_sic_) car sans doute qu’il pourra justement servir dans de futures publications à haute valeur scientifique :)
Personnellement, je tiens même une liste de mes néologismes et apporte un soins particulier à les rendre acceptables.

Comment: La biologie aurait été mon domaine de prédilection, je ne dis pas. Mais dans le cas présent, c'est un bête travail de programmation basé sur un logiciel de représentation de systèmes multi-agents^^

Answer (score 1):

Je ne sais pas si le mot existe déjà, mais à partir de la question j'imagine **méiopause**.

Comment: Quand bien même ça existerait, ce serait encore trop spécifique, puisqu'uniquement lié à la méiose. Je cherche un terme qui puisse s'appliquer à n'importe quel organisme^^"

Comment: Certes, mais on peut arguer que même les organismes tels que les humains utilisent la méiose pour se reproduire.

Answer (score 1):

Plutôt que de 'néologiciser' pourquoi ne pas utiliser l'antéposition '`a-`'

> passer (ou progresser) vers un état *a-reproductif* ou d'*a-reproduction*

qui reste lisible pour un plébéien francophone, surtout si le '`-`' signe bien l'intention privative de l'action envisagée.